# Kafka consumer is processing all messages at startup

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka, and am developing a personal project with a few services and the communication between them is made through Kafka and I am using Confluent for housing Kafka remotely.

All works fine, but when I startup a server it will try to process all the old messages in the topics that were generated as I was testing the system.

I would like to avoid this because it is time consuming and those messages were already processed, when the server was up the last time. Is there any way to prevent this in the development environment?

Am I even using Kafka correctly? Are there good practises that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "server", I assume you mean consumer. The *broker* server doesn't process data, only stores it.

If you have `auto.offset.reset=earliest` + `enable.auto.commit=false` + are not committing the records in your code (or are overall using a new `group.id` each time), this is the expected behavior since your `group.id` is not tracking already consumed data.

Since you're now in a situation where you have processed data, but no stored offsets, first set a static group id, then your options include

- re-process all the data again, accepting the duplicates, perhaps adding some conditional filter in your consumer code to skip records
- skip all processed and un-processed data and only start consuming brand-new records after the consumer starts, by either setting a new `group.id` + `auto.offset.reset=latest`, or use `consumer.seekToEnd()` / the `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI tool ; downside of setting `auto.offset.reset=latest` is that you might run into a situation where the consumer group has been idle too long, and the group expires, causing you to go back to the end of the topic, even though there may still be un-processed data
- manually find the offsets for all the partitions for the last processed data and `consumer.seek()` to those offsets

Comment: Yes, I was actually changing the group Id every time. what is the best practise, changing the group id + `auto.offset.reset=latest`, or keeping it always the same?

Comment: Using a new one each time pollutes the cluster metadata. And you don't need to do that if you disable/don't auto-commit in the consumer. If you do commit the messages, then progress will be tracked between restarts, only if you keep it the same, which sounds like what you want. Or if you always want to start at the end of the topic, you can call the seekToEnd method of the consumer before polling